# Is the OpenSSH server using a fallback, hard-coded DH parameter for 2048bits?

Tags: diffie-hellman, openssh

I'm toying around with OpenSSH configs and poking at the Diffie-Hellman parameters.  I'm using GDSSecurity's [tool](https://github.com/GDSSecurity/SSH-Weak-DH) to check DH settings and [this page](https://sshsec.zkpq.ca/) to view other SSH settings.

For funsies, I removed all moduli smaller than 4096 bits from `/etc/ssh/moduli`:

```
$ awk '{print $5}' /etc/ssh/moduli | sort | uniq
4095
6143
8191
```

I'd expect that the key-exchange should fail if the client accepts only 2048 bit or 3072 bit groups.  Interestingly, it does fail in the latter case, but *does not* in the former, 2048 bit case.

```
KEX proposal client: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
KEX proposal server: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
KEX algorithm chosen: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
KEX client group sizes: min = 2048, nbits = 2048, max = 2048
KEX server-chosen group size in bits: 2048
Warning: Permanently added 'test,x.x.x.x' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
KEX proposal client: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
KEX proposal server: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
KEX algorithm chosen: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
KEX client group sizes: min = 3072, nbits = 3072, max = 3072
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to x.x.x.x: DH GEX group out of range
```

The aforementioned site also claims a successful key exchange using a 2048 bit group.

I know too little about the details of neither the SSH protocol or OpenSSH to understand what's going on here.  Does OpenSSH use a fallback parameter if no appropriate group is available from the moduli file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fallback DH groups are defined [in source code here](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/8408218c1ca88cb17d15278174a24a94a6f65fe1/dh.c#L346). The current group can be 2k or 4k. But it really depends on which version are you using (there were some changes recently).

Note the [RFC 4419](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4419.txt), which specifies:

> Servers and clients SHOULD support groups with a modulus length of k
>      bits, where 1024 <= k <= 8192.  The recommended values for min and
>      max are 1024 and 8192, respectively.

And the recent release notes for future [openssh-7.2](http://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2016-February/034822.html):

> - ssh(1), sshd(8): increase the minimum modulus size supported for
>     diffie-hellman-group-exchange to 2048 bits.